# a way to count the number of cycles of an given attribute in a given dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, signals

i want to find the number of cycles in the given data set of motor fault current , it's given by the motor currents which were measured at different times , i want to know if it can even be considered a signal or it's just a pattern ?

[motor fault current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dKM1.png)

i tried some libraries , but they're for different conditions like they have zero crossing points for signals used and i can't find a point that i can turn into zero crossing for this as the motor current is always +ve and as such it just fluctuates with time a bit , and thus i'm getting a plot

```
data = pd.read_csv("healthy.csv")
y = np.array(data.Current_A)
x = data.index
date_array = pd.array(data.TimeStamp)
plt.plot(date_array,y)
```

[i used the 3ph healthy motor current dataset here , one thing , the dataset has whitespace as" Current-A" , it should be fixed as "Current_A"](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/gxdd74czwh/1)

Comment: this should be a fairly trivial question, but you need to provide some sample data / code for us to work with

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have already identified a key problem in your question - how do you identify a cycle? As you pointed out, the value is always positive, so you can't simply count zero-crossings. However, a few simple approaches you can try are:

- Subtract a bias, and then count zero crossings : If you know what the average value of the signal is going to be, you can subtract that average value from the signal to bring the plot back down to zero, and then count zero crossings. For example, in your attached image, since the plot alternates more or less between the extremes of 2.2 and 2.8 (approximately), if you subtract 2.5 from the signal and then count zero crossings, you should get pretty close. One downside of this is that it misses 'cycles' where the value doesn't cross the new zero cleanly. However, at that point, you need to start thinking again about your definition of a full 'cycle' and whether these cases count as a cycle for your purposes.
- As an extension of the above, if you have a system where the signal is slowly drifting over time, instead of a constant bias that you subtract from the signal, you can calculate the average bias over a sliding window and subtract that to calculate the zero crossings. This approach can fail if the signal drifts suddenly or the sliding window can't keep up with the speed of the change of the bias, but if your signal is as well behaved as in the provided image, it shouldn't be an issue.
- If you define your cycles only as peaks and valleys in the signal, then you can calculate the first and/or second derivatives of the signal to count the local maxima or minima. If you plot a separate graph where the values are the difference between two successive values in the first graph (the first order difference), then the zero-crossings in this new graph are either peaks or valleys in your original signal. If you also calculate the second derivative, then the sign of the second derivative will tell you whether it's a local maxima or a minima, and a complete cycle is the count of either one of them. This approach is immune to drift, but it's very sensitive to any noise that might be present in the signal, so if your signal is noisy, you might need to run it through a low-pass filter first to get rid of the noise before applying this approach.